# Проверка наличия символа в строке C++

Tags: c++, массивы, строки

Задача такова: необходимо ввести символ и проверить к какому алфавиту и регистру 
он принадлежит. С латинскими буквами все нормально,но проблемы возникают с кириллицей. Подскажите что не так в моей программе.
Код данной задачи:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");
char i;
cin >> i;

char ENG [] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
char eng [] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
char RU [] = "АБВГДЭЕЖЗЫИКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЬЪЮЯЁ";
char ru [] = "aбвгдеёжзыиклмнопрстуфхцчшщьъюяё";

for (int h = 0;h <= 26;h++)
{
if(i == ENG[h]){cout  <<"ENG";break;}
if(i == eng[h]){cout <<"eng";break;}
                                        }
for (int b = 0;b <=33;b++)
{
    if(i == RU[b]){cout  <<"RU";break;}
    if(i == ru[b]){cout <<"ru";break;}
                                        }

return a.exec();
                                        }
```

Comment: Выложите тип кодировки вашего исходного файла. Какой тип кодировке в системе по умолчанию? Какой язык по умолчанию?

Comment: Я к тому, что вы пишите в char*, а это, максимум ASCII

Comment: Распечатайте размер русского алфавита. Мне кажется там будет не 33, а 66

Comment: @pavel >>будет не 33, а 66<< А с чего это? Я вижу 33, при условии что в системе язык по умолчанию "Русский", ну и кодировка сорсов в ASCII/ANSI

Comment: В общем, нужна кодировка. Если не велосипедить, я бы использовал обычный std::string/std::wstring и делал бы find. Без всяких циклов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для проверки символа по ограниченному нулем массиву char используйте `strchr`, т.е. условие `if(strchr(массив, символ))` вместо цикла.

P.S. Использовать `i` для символа, а `b`, `h` для индексов, это "удачный" способ затруднить чтение кода...